# BLE Mesh with Google Home and Apple Homekit

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, iot, google-home, mesh-network

I'm currently in a project where we want to build up a BLE Mesh system with up to 100 nodes.
We are struggling to find out, how it is possible to connect the Mesh network to google home or apple homekit. If there is a phone, a connection to google home and apple home kit is possible over an IP protocol, but if the mesh is without phone, is it still possible to connect both systems into the mesh network?

Comment: For a gateway to connect to HomeKit there needs to be a suitable iOS device on the IP network; a phone, an iPad, an AppleTV or a HomePod

Comment: Ok, but what does an end device needs to satisfy to be compliant with HomeKit and Google Home? Somehow the IP network needs to be interfaced to BLE Mesh, right? Will the be done on the IOS device itself?

Comment: You can connect to a HomeKit accessory over BLE or IP.  You could expose each device as a BLE HomeKit accessory, but I don't think that would work well with your scenario; the user would need to add each device separately.  Probably a better approach is to implement a HomeKit gateway; This provides access to a number of HomeKit accessories via a single connection, either IP or BLE. - See https://developer.apple.com/homekit/. The gateway could be one of your existing devices or a specialised device depending on the processing power of your existing device

Comment: In the end, a user can have only 1 device or up to 100 and every device should provide the same functionality. All devices are in a BLE Mesh network, so when I can pair HomeKit with one device, I should be able to communicate with everyone. Apple provides this HomeKit Accessory Protocol (HAP), can I then specify there myself, how in the end the network looks like and what devices are online? Works google home the same? I could not find any proprietary protocol like HAP for Apple HomeKit.

Comment: I don’t know anything about Google Home. If each device is a an independent HomeKit accessory then the user would need to add each one individually to their home and they can’t really communicate via a mesh.  I think you will need one to act as a gateway and expose the other accessories. If your are looking to make and sell the devices then you will need to join the mfi program And get access to the HomeKit documentation and specifications.

Answer (score 0):

HAP specified only BLE accessories can not be controlled can be bridged, based on this, Hue lightbulb can not be meshed and bridged in Homekit.